# Using VPC connector in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have ended up in a tricky situation regarding the usage of serverless vpc-connectors in Cloud-Run. The service needs to call both other internal(e.g only allow invocation via internal traffic) cloud run services and some external services/urls. Given the two options for routing through the connector, namely (1. Route only traffic to private IPS through the connector) and (2. Route all traffic through the connector), it seems impossible to me to configure the connector in such a way that makes it correctly resolve both external and internal URLs.

When going with the first option, the URLs for internal cloud run services are not properly resolved but the external ones are. There are no static IPs for cloud-run services so using "internal" IPs is not an option.

When choosing the second option, the internal URLs are resolved properly but not the external ones.

Is there a solution to this situation?

Comment: You can't achieve what you want. In addition, relying on the static public IP is not a good design, but I know that legacy/old design app sometime need that.

Comment: https://chuntezuka.medium.com/connect-2-cloud-run-services-internally-with-serverless-vpc-connector-64e3bdb4d39e

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the VPC Serverless connection is to provide internal access from your Serverless Application to the internal GCP VPC resources as pointed out in the following document [1].

Being said that, if an application deployed through Cloud Run needs GCP external resources; that should be handled by the composition of the image used itself, not by the VPC Serverless connection.

The second part I could get from your response is that you have multiple services configured in Cloud Run and need to communicate among them.

For this part, I want to point out that maybe the best approach instead of the VPC serverless connection would be to merge your services and package them into one single docker file.

You can find examples on how to run multiple services in a container in the following document [2].

Once you have created a docker image with the services merged you can store it in any supported registry and deploy it with Cloud Run as stated in the following document [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access

[2] https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

[3] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying

Answer (score 0):

The correct option if you want to reach both internal and external URLs is the
"Route only traffic to private IPS through the connector".
As google public documentation states: "Only requests to RFC 1918 and RFC 6598 IP address ranges or internal DNS names are routed to your VPC network. All other requests are routed directly to the internet". [1]

If you are having problems reaching the internal URLs when you select this option most probably you are blocking them at the firewall level in the VPC Subnet.

To check the firewall rules in your project you can run the following command in gcloud console:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc

Comment: Looks like firewall rules have no effect on Cloud Run. Only when I change from Allow only internal to Allow All traffic that Service B is accessible from service A (shows that firewall has nothing to do with that), otherwise I get 403, and I'm kind of not surprised. When Service A is not configured to route all traffic through the VPC connector and tries to access service B (which has "Allow internal traffic only" for ingress) via its public URL, then service A won't get assigned an internal IP, and service B will receive the request from Service A and reject it because it's not internal.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress#:~:text=For%20requests%20from%20other%20Cloud%20Run%20services%20or%20from%20Cloud%20Functions%20in%20the%20same%20project%2C%20connect%20the%20service%20or%20function%20to%20a%20VPC%20network%20and%20route%20all%20egress%20through%20the%20connector%2C%20as%20described%20in%20Connecting%20to%20a%20VPC%20network.%20Note%20that%20the%20IAM%20invoker%20permission%20is%20still%20enforced.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could not make external requests from my 'app engine' API after setting up the VPC connector.

using the [connection test](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-intelligence/connectivity/tests/list) helped me figure out the issue, I had to create a cloud NAT for the external request to comply.

https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/nat/list